# Jenkins: How can I make a remotely submitted job use default parameter values?

Tags: jenkins

I am triggering a parametrized Jenkins job remotely using the [Remote Access API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) like this:

```
url=http://<ci-host>/job/<jobname>/build
json="{\"parameter\": [{\"name\": \"A_NAME\", \"value\": \"a_value\"}]}"
curl -X POST $url -d token=zorn --data-urlencode json="$json"
```

I want Jenkins to use the configured default value for one of my parameters, but it seems to be expecting values for all of the parameters.

If I leave out a parameter, the job sees it as an empty string.

Is there a way to make it use the configured default value for a parameter?

EDIT:
The solution (as per Daniel S.) was to use `buildWithParameters` as follows:

```
url=http://<ci-host>/job/<jobname>/buildWithParameters
curl -s -X POST $url
```

ANOTHER EDIT:
But now the problem is that `buildWithParameters` does not work on a job with no parameters. So it cannot be used for a generic script to start all my jobs.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try to use `buildWithParameters` instead of `build`, i.e.

```
http://<ci-host>/job/<jobname>/buildWithParameters
```

Comment: Complications ensue with security / authorization in place. You can read some good pointers in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16181067/366749).