# How to run a parameterized Jenkins job automatically

Tags: build, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a Jenkins job that takes a source branch name as a parameter. Now I want to schedule the job to run at midnight everyday. As you always need to input the parameter even though the default value has been set. So my question is, is there a way to automate the execution of a parameterized job?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer which is writing a shell script by using Jenkins Remote Access API. An existing question ([Jenkins: How can I make a remotely submitted job use default parameter values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858991/jenkins-how-can-i-make-a-remotely-submitted-job-use-default-parameter-values)) is related. One also can check here (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) to find more information.

Comment: Actually it is just as simple as scheduling the job as long as the parameter default values have been set.

Comment: Why write a shell script rather than simply scheduling a job with the params? And if you had to write a script, why not do a groovy scripted flow, and let your job be OS independent?

Answer (score 5):

Schedule a separate recurring job and use the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to trigger your parameterized build.